# How to fix low-resolution wallpaper?

Tags: unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, desktop-background

Whenever my computer starts and I log in, the desktop wallpaper loads at half resolution. Everything else is native resolution, and if I reselect the wallpaper it loads at full resolution. It's JUST the wallpaper image that renders at low resolution and ONLY the first time it's loaded.

I am using Unity on Ubuntu 14.10. I am running an NVIDIA 9600GSO with proprietary drivers with two monitors, one 2048x1152 physically on top of one 3840x2160 monitor. Both monitors are at their native resolution. I can't think of any particular reason why the wallpaper loads at a lower resolution.

Comment: Could be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1428076